# How do I enable Pop-up window when clicking user story

Tags: azure-devops

Can anyone check if there is a setting to toggle if I want to enable the pop-up window when clicking the user story or task?
I remember I have that before - but right now, it will just open it in the same window. not as a pop-up.

Comment: can you please make your question more specific e.g. "How do I enable Pop-up window when clicking Azure DevOps work item"

Answer (score 5):

When opening an item you see a resize icon [image: resize icon] - when you click it the work item is switched back to pop up. This then also applies when you open work items in the future.

ADDED:
However there seems to be a difference between opening from "Work items" or "Query" and from "Backlog" or "Sprints". From "Backlog" and "Sprints" a pop-up is displayed when you use the above mentioned icon. From "Work items" or "Query" this has no relevance and work item is displayed on full screen - also allowing you to scroll up/down.

Comment: Hello Kai. thank you.
to clarify - my issue is that when I click the work item, it will go to the https://XXXX.visualstudio.com/XXXXX/?workitem=1103323, instead of popping up a small window.

any idea?

Comment: I see. There seems to be a difference between opening from "Work items" or "Query" and from "Backlog". From "Backlog" and "Sprints" a pop-up is display when you use the above mentioned icon. From "Work items" or "Query" this has no relevance and work item is display on full screen - also allowing you to scroll up/down.

Answer (score 2):

Open the *Task* or *User Story* and press the <kbd>z</kbd> button on your keyboard, or simply exit the full screen mode by clicking this icon:

[image: Screenshot with button highlighted]

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone check if there is a setting to toggle if I want to enable the pop-up window when clicking the user story or task?

I am afraid there is no such setting to toggle the pop-up window when clicking the user story or task.

That because the different response type in the source code to the event of opening the link.

When we open the user story or task in the **Work items** in the Azure devops, the event type is to jump to the new link address, we could check it from the source code:

[image]

But if we open the user story or task in the **Backlog** or **Sprints**,  the event type is **UI draggable**:

[image]

So, I am afraid there is no such settings to change the toggle the pop-up window.

Besides, on the old version of TFS, like TFS2017. the event type is **open the link on the workitems tab**. This may be the cause of the vague impression you have.

Comment: Looking at the other answers in this thread, it's a simple button to click in the UI.
This answer doesn't seem to give an answer, just a "it's not possible" remark.